# How can I use long options with the Bash getopts builtin?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, getopts

I am trying to parse a `-temp` option with Bash getopts. I'm calling my script like this:

```
./myscript -temp /foo/bar/someFile
```

Here is the code I'm using to parse the options.

```
while getopts "temp:shots:o:" option; do
    case $option in
        temp) TMPDIR="$OPTARG" ;;
        shots) NUMSHOTS="$OPTARG" ;;
        o) OUTFILE="$OPTARG" ;;
        *) usage ;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

[ $# -lt 1 ] && usage
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Comment: I disagree of it being duplicate. That question is more general how to parse, while this one is more specific as how to parse long options in perticular.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`getopts` can only parse short options.

Most systems also have an external `getopt` command, but getopt is not standard, and is generally broken by design as it can't handle all arguments safely (arguments with whitespace and empty arguments), only GNU getopt can handle them safely, but only if you use it in a GNU-specific way.

The easier choice is to use neither, just iterate the script's arguments with a while-loop and do the parsing yourself.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 for an example.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel here, just use getopts and look-up other ways to parse long arguments, or trick it like the @mcoolive shows here

Answer (score 112):

As other people explained, getopts doesn't parse long options. You can use getopt, but it's not portable (and it is broken on some platform...)

As a workaround, you can implement a shell loop. Here an example that transforms long options to short ones before using the standard getopts command (it's simpler in my opinion):

```
# Transform long options to short ones
for arg in "$@"; do
  shift
  case "$arg" in
    '--help')   set -- "$@" '-h'   ;;
    '--number') set -- "$@" '-n'   ;;
    '--rest')   set -- "$@" '-r'   ;;
    '--ws')     set -- "$@" '-w'   ;;
    *)          set -- "$@" "$arg" ;;
  esac
done

# Default behavior
number=0; rest=false; ws=false

# Parse short options
OPTIND=1
while getopts "hn:rw" opt
do
  case "$opt" in
    'h') print_usage; exit 0 ;;
    'n') number=$OPTARG ;;
    'r') rest=true ;;
    'w') ws=true ;;
    '?') print_usage >&2; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1) # remove options from positional parameters
```

Comment: This is great, except that it fails to notify the user properly if an invalid argument is passed, instead stating `illegal option -- -`. I added the following to my script to help:
`"--"*)           usage ${arg}; exit 2;;`

Comment: It may be a good idea. My example can be improved in the same way to allow a syntax like "--separator=STRING". I chose to implement a simple loop and do not allow all possible syntaxes. It can be improved.

Comment: This is the most straightforward solution that I have found so far. Which allow you keep using the getopts and also support `--` style. Nice!

Comment: Works as a charm. Thank you for sharing your solution.

Comment: Please extend with a long option that requires an argument.

Comment: @mcoolive curious to know if this could work inside a function? My initial test showed that `$@` disappear and `$@=$@" seems like a wrong fix...

Comment: @mcoolive, I am using your example in a script but I do not understand why `shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)` is needed. Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter `shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)` is useful when your command has other arguments after positional parameters, typically what is after `--` on the command line.

Comment: May I know how we can get the argument of the long option such as `r=${OPTARG}` ?

Comment: @ikhvjs If the long option is passed with the syntax "--long arg", then it is substituted by "-l arg", and you can get it in the getups loop as you do for any short option. So yes, with OPTARG.

Comment: So, can I use only long options without transforming to short options?

Comment: @KalibZen Yes you can. See the other answers for a custom implementation. Or you can give up on portability.

Comment: Unfortunately, because that way the original arguments are changed... later we don't know which were the original arguments. 

If we have to warn the user about something he has used, we have no way of showing e.g. an error message quoting the argument that the user utilized incorrectly. Is there any good remedy?

Comment: @Ganton Only known long options are replaced. Other values are kept unchanged. Do you have an example? When I want relevant error messages, I do tests very early in my script. As far I know, there is no way to bump original command line and keep portability. If you give up on portability, you may use an array. But if you give up on portability, you should consider to use getopt (with no "s")...

Comment: @mcoolive *“> Do you have an example?”* I have a wrapper script for adb and other programs, adb is the software that does its related error management and when it was executed `wrapper pull --overwrite` then the wrapper showed `adb: error: failed to stat remote object '-o': No such file or directory`. *“> you should consider to use getopt (with no "s").”* I ended up using it, it solved the aforementioned problems, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

`getopts` is  used by shell procedures to parse positional parameters of 1 character only
(no GNU-style long options (--myoption) or XF86-style long options (-myoption))

Answer (score 3):

the simplest way to achieve this is with the help of **`getopt`**  and **`--longoptions`**

try this , hope this is useful

```
# Read command line options
ARGUMENT_LIST=(
    "input1"
    "input2"
    "input3"
)



# read arguments
opts=$(getopt \
    --longoptions "$(printf "%s:," "${ARGUMENT_LIST[@]}")" \
    --name "$(basename "$0")" \
    --options "" \
    -- "$@"
)


echo $opts

eval set --$opts

while true; do
    case "$1" in
    --input1)  
        shift
        empId=$1
        ;;
    --input2)  
        shift
        fromDate=$1
        ;;
    --input3)  
        shift
        toDate=$1
        ;;
      --)
        shift
        break
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

and this is how - you call the shell script

```
myscript.sh --input1 "ABC" --input2 "PQR" --input2 "XYZ"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true that **builtin bash `getopts`** only parse short options,
but you can still add few lines of scripting to make getopts handles long options.

Here is a part of code found in http://www.uxora.com/unix/shell-script/22-handle-long-options-with-getopts

```
  #== set options ==#
SCRIPT_OPTS=':fbF:B:-:h'
typeset -A ARRAY_OPTS
ARRAY_OPTS=(
    [foo]=f
    [bar]=b
    [foobar]=F
    [barfoo]=B
    [help]=h
    [man]=h
)

  #== parse options ==#
while getopts ${SCRIPT_OPTS} OPTION ; do
    #== translate long options to short ==#
    if [[ "x$OPTION" == "x-" ]]; then
        LONG_OPTION=$OPTARG
        LONG_OPTARG=$(echo $LONG_OPTION | grep "=" | cut -d'=' -f2)
        LONG_OPTIND=-1
        [[ "x$LONG_OPTARG" = "x" ]] && LONG_OPTIND=$OPTIND || LONG_OPTION=$(echo $OPTARG | cut -d'=' -f1)
        [[ $LONG_OPTIND -ne -1 ]] && eval LONG_OPTARG="\$$LONG_OPTIND"
        OPTION=${ARRAY_OPTS[$LONG_OPTION]}
        [[ "x$OPTION" = "x" ]] &&  OPTION="?" OPTARG="-$LONG_OPTION"

        if [[ $( echo "${SCRIPT_OPTS}" | grep -c "${OPTION}:" ) -eq 1 ]]; then
            if [[ "x${LONG_OPTARG}" = "x" ]] || [[ "${LONG_OPTARG}" = -* ]]; then 
                OPTION=":" OPTARG="-$LONG_OPTION"
            else
                OPTARG="$LONG_OPTARG";
                if [[ $LONG_OPTIND -ne -1 ]]; then
                    [[ $OPTIND -le $Optnum ]] && OPTIND=$(( $OPTIND+1 ))
                    shift $OPTIND
                    OPTIND=1
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi

    #== options follow by another option instead of argument ==#
    if [[ "x${OPTION}" != "x:" ]] && [[ "x${OPTION}" != "x?" ]] && [[ "${OPTARG}" = -* ]]; then 
        OPTARG="$OPTION" OPTION=":"
    fi

    #== manage options ==#
    case "$OPTION" in
        f  ) foo=1 bar=0                    ;;
        b  ) foo=0 bar=1                    ;;
        B  ) barfoo=${OPTARG}               ;;
        F  ) foobar=1 && foobar_name=${OPTARG} ;;
        h ) usagefull && exit 0 ;;
        : ) echo "${SCRIPT_NAME}: -$OPTARG: option requires an argument" >&2 && usage >&2 && exit 99 ;;
        ? ) echo "${SCRIPT_NAME}: -$OPTARG: unknown option" >&2 && usage >&2 && exit 99 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((${OPTIND} - 1))
```

Here is a test:

```
# Short options test
$ ./foobar_any_getopts.sh -bF "Hello world" -B 6 file1 file2
foo=0 bar=1
barfoo=6
foobar=1 foobar_name=Hello world
files=file1 file2

# Long and short options test
$ ./foobar_any_getopts.sh --bar -F Hello --barfoo 6 file1 file2
foo=0 bar=1
barfoo=6
foobar=1 foobar_name=Hello
files=file1 file2
```

Otherwise **in recent Korn Shell** ksh93, `getopts` can naturally parse long options and even display a man page alike. (see http://www.uxora.com/unix/shell-script/20-getopts-with-man-page-and-long-options)

**Michel VONGVILAY.**

Comment: Nice one, thank you. Unfortunately, it breaks if an argument contains '=' or an argument is an empty string. Should I suggest a version that supports '=' and empty strings as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question was posted over 2 years ago, I found myself needing support for XFree86-style long options too; and I also wanted to take what I could from getopts. Consider the GCC switch `-rdynamic`. I mark `r` as the flag letter, and expect `dynamic` within `$OPTARG`...but, I want to reject `-r dynamic`, while accepting other options following `r`.

The idea I've put below builds on the observation that `$OPTIND` will be one larger than otherwise if space (a gap) follows the flag. So, I define a bash variable to hold the previous value of `$OPTIND`, called `$PREVOPTIND`, and update it at the end of the `while` loop. If `$OPTIND` is `1` greater than `$PREVOPTIND`, we have no gap (i.e. `-rdynamic`); and `$GAP` is set to `false`. If instead `$OPTIND` is `2` greater than `$PREVOPTIND`, we *do* have a gap (e.g. `-r   dynamic`), and `$GAP` is set to `true`.

```
usage() { echo usage: error from $1; exit -1; }

OPTIND=1
PREVOPTIND=$OPTIND
while getopts "t:s:o:" option; do
  GAP=$((OPTIND-(PREVOPTIND+1)))
  case $option in
    t) case "${OPTARG}" in
         emp)                  # i.e. -temp
           ((GAP)) && usage "-${option} and ${OPTARG}"
           TMPDIR="$OPTARG"
           ;;
         *)
           true
           ;;
       esac
       ;;
    s) case "${OPTARG}" in
         hots)                 # i.e. -shots
           ((GAP)) && usage
           NUMSHOTS="$OPTARG"
           ;;
         *) usage "-${option} and ${OPTARG}" ;;
       esac
       ;;
    o) OUTFILE="$OPTARG" ;;
    *) usage "-${option} and ${OPTARG}" ;;
  esac
  PREVOPTIND=$OPTIND
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the *getopts* Bash builtin for long options--at least, not without having to build your own parsing functions. You should take a look at the */usr/bin/getopt* binary instead (provided on my system by the [util-linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) package; your mileage may vary).

See getopt(1) for specific invocation options.

Comment: I don't think `/usr/bin/getopt` supports long options either.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @mcoolive .

I was able to use your $@ idea to convert whole word and long options to single letter options. Wanted to note to anyone using this idea that I also had to include `shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)` prior to running the arguments through the getopts loop.

Totally different purpose but this is working well.

```
# convert long word options to short word for ease of use and portability

for argu in "$@"; do
  shift
  #echo "curr arg = $1"
  case "$argu" in
"-start"|"--start")
                   # param=param because no arg is required
                   set -- "$@" "-s"
                   ;;
"-pb"|"--pb"|"-personalbrokers"|"--personalbrokers")
                   # pb +arg required
                   set -- "$@" "-p $1"; #echo "arg=$argu"
                   ;;
"-stop"|"--stop")
                   # param=param because no arg is required 
                   set -- "$@" "-S" 
                   ;;
                #  the catch all option here removes all - symbols from an
                #  argument. if an option is attempted to be passed that is
                #  invalid, getopts knows what to do...
               *)  [[ $(echo $argu | grep -E "^-") ]] && set -- "$@" "${argu//-/}" || echo "no - symbol. not touching $argu" &>/dev/null
                   ;;
esac
done

#echo -e "\n final option conversions = $@\n"
# remove options from positional parameters for getopts parsing
shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)

declare -i runscript=0
# only p requires an argument hence the p:
 while getopts "sSp:" param; do
[[ "$param" == "p" ]] && [[ $(echo $OPTARG | grep -E "^-") ]] && funcUsage "order" 
#echo $param
#echo "OPTIND=$OPTIND"
case $param in
s)
       OPTARG=${OPTARG/ /}
       getoptsRan=1
       echo "$param was passed and this is it's arg $OPTARG"
       arg0=start
       ;;
 p)
       OPTARG=${OPTARG/ /}
       getoptsRan=1
       echo "$param was passed and this is it's arg $OPTARG"
       [[ "$OPTARG" == "all" ]] && echo -e "argument \"$OPTARG\" accepted. continuing." && (( runscript += 1 )) || usage="open"
       [[ $( echo $pbString | grep -w "$OPTARG" ) ]] && echo -e "pb $OPTARG was validated. continuing.\n" && (( runscript += 1 )) || usage="personal"
       [[ "$runscript" -lt "1" ]] && funcUsage "$usage" "$OPTARG"
       arg0=start
       ;;
S)
       OPTARG=${OPTARG/ /}
       getoptsRan=1
       echo "$param was passed and this is it's arg $OPTARG"
       arg0=stop
       ;;
*)
       getoptsRan=1
       funcUsage
       echo -e "Invalid argument\n"
       ;;
esac
done
funcBuildExcludes "$@"
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple DIY if you get trouble to use the built-in `getopts`:

Use:

```sh
$ ./test-args.sh --a1 a1 --a2 "a 2" --a3 --a4= --a5=a5 --a6="a 6"
a1 = "a1"
a2 = "a 2"
a3 = "TRUE"
a4 = ""
a5 = "a5"
a6 = "a 6"
a7 = ""
```

Script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function main() {
    ARGS=`getArgs "$@"`

    a1=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a1`
    a2=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a2`
    a3=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a3`
    a4=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a4`
    a5=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a5`
    a6=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a6`
    a7=`echo "$ARGS" | getNamedArg a7`

    echo "a1 = \"$a1\""
    echo "a2 = \"$a2\""
    echo "a3 = \"$a3\""
    echo "a4 = \"$a4\""
    echo "a5 = \"$a5\""
    echo "a6 = \"$a6\""
    echo "a7 = \"$a7\""

    exit 0
}


function getArgs() {
    for arg in "$@"; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}


function getNamedArg() {
    ARG_NAME=$1

    sed --regexp-extended --quiet --expression="
        s/^--$ARG_NAME=(.*)\$/\1/p  # Get arguments in format '--arg=value': [s]ubstitute '--arg=value' by 'value', and [p]rint
        /^--$ARG_NAME\$/ {          # Get arguments in format '--arg value' ou '--arg'
            n                       # - [n]ext, because in this format, if value exists, it will be the next argument
            /^--/! p                # - If next doesn't starts with '--', it is the value of the actual argument
            /^--/ {                 # - If next do starts with '--', it is the next argument and the actual argument is a boolean one
                # Then just repla[c]ed by TRUE
                c TRUE
            }
        }
    "
}


main "$@"
```