# Using --getopts to pick up whole word flags

Tags: bash, unix, getopts

Can getopts be used to pick up whole-word flags?

Something as follows:

```
while getopts ":abc --word" opt; do
    case ${opt} in
        a) SOMETHING
            ;;
        ...
        --word) echo "Do something else."
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Trying to pick up those double-dash flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found one way to do this:

```
while getopts ":abc-:" opt; do
    case ${opt} in
        a) echo "Do something"
            ;;
        ...
        -)
            case ${OPTARG} in
                "word"*) echo "This works"
                    ;;
            esac
    esac
done
```

By adding -: to the opstring and adding a sub-case using $OPTARG, you can pick up the long option you want.  If you want to include an argument for that option, you can add * or =* to the case and pick up the argument.

Comment: Pity that this requires the word flags to be prefixed with a double dash. How can I achieve e.g. GCC's `-rdynamic` ?

Comment: This method only works for a single longer argument. Any extra multi-char argument is not parsed.

Comment: Ah true.  I think there's probably a modification that allows for more than one multi-char args.  Haven't thought about it in a long time, but I can offer an edit once I resolve it.

Answer (score 10):

Basically Ark's answer but easier and quicker to read than the mywiki page:

```
#!/bin/bash
# example_args.sh

while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
  case $1 in
    -s | --state) S="$2" ;;
    -u | --user) U="$2" ;;
    -a | --aarg) A="$2" ;;
    -b | --barg) B="$2" ;;

  esac
  shift
done

echo $S $U, $A $B
```

`$#` represents the number of arguments, `-gt` is "greater than", `$1` is the flag in this case, and `$2` is the flag's value.

`./example_args.sh --state IAM --user Yeezy -a Do --barg it`
results in:

```
IAM Yeezy, Do it
```

Comment: If you want to validate the arguments using something like `*) echo "Unknown argument '$1'."; exit 1 ;;`, make sure you use `shift` with the arguments that need a passed value: `-a | --aarg) A="$2"; shift ;;`

Comment: Using the same code as yours but if I don't pass any arguments to the script inside the while loop `$#` is always looping between 1 and 2. I can't figure out why this happening :(

Comment: just use an if statement before the while. check [ $# -eq 0 ] to see if there are exactly 0 arguments. then you can print out an error and exit 1, so the script would never get to the while loop

Comment: also isn't the first default argument always script name or something? is this of importance here?

Answer (score 6):

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035
Credit goes to: [How can I use long options with the Bash getopts builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022592/how-can-i-use-long-options-with-the-bash-getopts-builtin).

Comment: Thanks.  Found a possible workaround by including "-:" in the optstring.  Wondering what the pitfalls to this approach might be.